# Creating a video file from a group of PGM files in python

Tags: python, pgm

My python program generates a collection of binary files. I create pgm (portable bitmap files) using this binary data. I would like to create a video using each of the pgm files as a frame in my video.

I have had a look an mencoder but I dont think it supports pgm files

Can anyone offer any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "PGM" is identical with "Portable GrayMap Files", cross-browser command line video processing tool [**ffmpeg**](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) can decode them: [**List of FFMPeg Codecs on Wikipedia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg#Codecs)

Check out the FFMPEG FAQ: [**3.2 How do I encode single pictures into movies?**](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#SEC14)

On how to use FFMpeg with Python, check [**this SO question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908411/how-to-use-ffmpeg). There is a wrapper for Python, but I can't find any statements on how good it is.

If in doubt, just call it from the command line.

Comment: Thanks Pekka, just the info I was needing